# "#_no-deeplink-found_ " is automatically appending to home page url

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using wordpress for a website. When I hit home page,"**#*no-deeplink-found***" is automatically is appending to the url. I have no idea about deep links and why it is appending to the url.

I have searched all the plugins settings, fond no solution to remove it. I have disabled some SEO related plugins, but found no solution for it.

Please help me to remove this. I don't want any additional parameters to be added to the homepage url.

Below are the screen snap of the issue:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvZq8.png)

**Additional Info**
Theme : solomedic

Any help will be appreciated!!!!!

Comment: Anything to do with your affiliate marketing?

Comment: Hi @Alex, nothing to do with affiliate marketing.

Answer (score 0):

In a Similar case of mine, an **issue found with "WP-Bakery page editor > Layerslider"** component in WordPress page editor. When we delete this layer, page loads fine. Therefore, you may test by deleting this layer or verifying its setting.